# What are appropriate ways to insert a new electrical outlet on a bedroom concrete wall?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, structural

I live in a home built in the 40s with exterior walls that seem to be cinderblocks filled with concrete, with a brick outer exterior.
In one bedroom, I have to run an extension cord across the room to the window for a window AC unit in the Summer, so I'd like to just put an outlet there.

I have two problems.

1. Because the wall is solid concrete, it makes it impossible to simply fish a wire from the attic down to the area I'd like to put the new outlet, as I would do on an interior wall.
2. I'm unsure if I will be violating a building code by cutting a hole large enough for the outlet box near the window. Because the window is so close, I'm assuming that I wouldn't be compromising the wall's ability to bear weight.

I don't want to run a piece of conduit down the bedroom wall, because it would be ugly in a bedroom.

A couple of things about this room-- Its carpet was cut too short by previous owners, so they put a tall 5" piece of trim with a smaller 2" piece of trim nailed to the bottom of it to make an L shape on the wall to cover the bare floor. The carpet padding and carpet create enough room for me to put the 1/2" MC below the tall piece of trim, and the small 2" piece juts out enough to completely hide the MC without overlapping directly on top of it.

A solution I thought of -

- For (1) getting the actual power to the outlet was to run some 1/2" diameter aluminum armored cable from a GFCI outlet in the same room beneath some thick baseboards. I'd set the baseboard on TOP of the wire (not in front of) so that there would be no chance of accidentally nailing the armored wire. It looks like it would work, but feels kind of hacky, so I'm hoping I'm not breaking any codes by doing that.
- For (2) cutting the hole and installing the outlet box, I'm thinking of just using an oscillating cutting tool, masonry drill, and a chisel to cut it neatly, and using construction adhesive to secure the box in place (after having cut a line for the armored wire to go up into the box)

If my solution is not breaking any building codes, and cutting the outlet hole is not breaking building codes, that solution is where I'm leaning.

I'm not a builder, so please excuse me if my ideas seem totally ridiculous.
Any new/alternative ideas are welcomed.

Comment: Could you clarify your baseboard idea - not sure I understand in front of vs. on top of. EMT is available in 1/2 inch size, but an even smaller raceway that is UL approved for indoor use is "Wiremold" 500 and 700 series. They don't look as clunky as normal conduit, are paintable and may fit behind baseboard. You could run in wiremold behind the baseboard, then have a short visible surface mounted wiremold run up the wall to a surface-mounted outlet.

Comment: This is just info on the sizing of wiremold raceway - I'm not sure there are any other UL approved brands in this raceway niche: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yl9CW.png

Comment: For securing the outlet box I think you'll have to use real fasteners intended for concrete, not just adhesive.

Comment: 12/2 MC seems to be almost 1/2 inch outer diameter - is that what you meant by "some 1/4" diameter aluminum armored cable " ?

Comment: @Armand Yes, so a couple of things about this room-- Its carpet was cut too short by previous owners, so they put a tall 5" piece of trim with a smaller 2" piece of trim nailed to the bottom of it to make an L shape on the wall.
The carpet padding and carpet create enough room for me to put the 1/2" MC below the tall piece of trim, and the small 2" piece juts out enough to completely hide the MC without overlapping directly on top of it.
yes you are right it is 1/2 inch not 1/4, I'll also clarify that in my question.

Comment: Pictures are your friend.

Comment: I'd like to help you figure this out, but I have some different ideas for how to accomplish your purpose. I would avoid the MC route. Usually, when I can't fish from the attic or between floors, I look at whether I could pop outside with conduit and then back in for the receptacle. If the house was built in the 40s you might not have much of an overhang on your roof. Pictures would help.

Answer (score 0):

If you can run the Electric in your attic over to the wall that you want the socket to be on, you can cut a small Channel down to where you want to install the socket and cut out an opening for it. All you have to do is secure it. Cement it back in, smooth the surface and if you do it right it'll look like it's never been cut.

As seen [here](https://freeimage.host/i/20200828-103049.q2ZY8P).
and [here](https://freeimage.host/i/HhT7Ege).

Answer (score 0):

I understand the concerns about having conduit running up the wall or across the room, and the "just under the baseboard" option sounds fine to me, but I am not 100% sure. You should consider [Legrand Wiremold](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Legrand-Wiremold-700-Series-10-ft-Metal-Surface-Raceway-Channel-in-White-700WH/100144606)  - it is a lot more "finished" looking than regular conduit.

But whether you use Wiremold, regular conduit, find a way to hide cables, or just drill holes and run cables through walls, I highly recommend surface mounting the junction box. It will be a lot easier than cutting a big hole in brick/block, and you can use a Wiremold (or similar) box rather than a bare steel box.